# How to replace words in a sentence with their POS tag generated with SpaCy efficiently?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy

How is it possible to replace words in a sentence with their respective PoS tags generated with SpaCy in an efficient way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not replace tags in a sentence because Python strings are immutable.

You can make another string with just the tags:

```py
>>> import spacy
>>> nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
>>> doc = nlp("Apple is looking at buying U.K. startup for $1 billion")
>>> " ".join(token.tag_ for token in doc)
'NNP VBZ VBG IN VBG NNP NN IN $ CD CD'
```

That example is based on the spaCy [documentation](https://spacy.io/usage/spacy-101#annotations-pos-deps).

If the tokens are split by several different non-space delimiters (called "multiple infix tokenization" in SpaCy), you would have to track that and the code would be more complex.